# How to pass string (not file) to openssl?

Tags: openssl

I want to encrypt a bunch of strings using openssl. How do I pass plaintext in console to openssl (instead of specifying input file which has plaintext).

openssl man page has only these two options related to input/output:

```
-in <file>     input file
-out <file>    output file
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

This works fine,

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in plain.txt -out encrypted.txt
```

If I omit the -out parameter I get encrypted string in console,

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -in plain.txt
```

But If I omit both -in and -out, I get an error - unknown option 'Encrypt ME',

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 "Encrypt ME"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this:

```
user@host:~$ echo "my string to encrypt" | openssl aes-256-cbc -e -a -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
a7svR6j/uAz4kY9jvWbJaUR/d5QdH5ua/vztLN7u/FE=
user@host:~$ echo "a7svR6j/uAz4kY9jvWbJaUR/d5QdH5ua/vztLN7u/FE=" | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
my string to encrypt
```

Or you could use command substitution:

```
user@host:~$ openssl aes-256-cbc -a -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv \
00000000000000000000000000000000 -in <(echo "my string to encrypt") -out encrypted.txt
```

---

The flags are documented in the manual page `man openssl-enc`:

- `-a`: base64 process the data. This means that if encryption is taking place the data is base64 encoded after encryption. If decryption is set then the input data is base64 decoded before being decrypted.
- `-d`: decrypt the input data.
- `-e`: encrypt the input data
- `-K`: the actual key to use: this must be represented as a string comprised only of hex digits. If only the key is specified, the IV must additionally specified using the -iv option. When both a key and a password are specified, the key given with the -K option will be used and the IV generated from the password will be taken. It probably does not make much sense to specify both key and password.
- `-iv`: the actual IV to use: this must be represented as a string comprised only of hex digits. When only the key is specified using the -K option, the IV must explicitly be defined. When a password is being specified using one of the other options, the IV is generated from this password.

Comment: Thanks chaos. 'command substitution' is what I was looking for.

Comment: In all of the answers here, echo is used without the "-n" option so it will include a trailing newline that will be included in the hash input.

Comment: What does -e do?

Comment: what does -K and -iv do??? Can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
echo encrypt Me | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

If your concerne is that a ps will show the plain text 'encrypt me', then you'd better sitck with file, beeing carefull to erase them.

Comment: Thanks. I am not concerned about command history but I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Enter multiline input, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to finish. `e='e'` will clear the env var, for privacy.

```
e=$(cat); echo "$e" | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -a; e='e'
```